# Electric Chair Submission

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, grappling, jujutsu

Is 'Electric Chair' submission in Brazilian Jiu Jitsu some kind of a knee bar or does it affect to any other area of the leg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my dim understanding, BJJ's electric chair can include a straight kneebar or twisting leglock element, but the primary aim is to sweep, or to submit with a hamstring or groin stretch.

Comment: Is 'groin stretch' a legal move?

Comment: As far as I know, it's legal at all belt levels for adults.

Comment: I love this move, it's one of my "go to" moves from half guard / lockdown.  I very rarely get the tap on the groin stretch, but depends on the person a fair bit.  But super effective as a sweep.

Comment: I have seen another submission same as 'Electric Chair' which is called 'Banana Split'. If am not mistaken, that submission also works on groin stretching.

Comment: For the IBJJF this technique is called "Submission techniques stretching legs apart" and is allow for everyone up 12 Years old

Answer (score 4):

As a submission it's mainly a groin / hamstring  stretch - effectively forcing your opponent into a "splits" type position.

It's been a go-to move of mine from under half-guard for a while, be aware that those with good flexibility won't tap so be prepared to switch to the sweep.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment as a new user, but this technique is IBJJF legal for everyone except kids under 12.

The banana split is usually reached fom the Truck, but there is a lot in common between it and the Electric chair submission.

If you watch the last match between Eddie and Royler, Eddie gives a textbook exhibition of the Electric Chair.

Comment: Yeah!! I've watched that match. Royler was struggling with the leg trap. If am not mistaken, the banana split can be executed when the opponent is at the turtle position.